# if overlay is present (element is display: block) push element underneath down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a large overlay on my site -- powered by `popify.js` the overlay works with a click function that binds '`display:block;`' *(this is my understanding)* to element that is default `display: none;` essentially a simple show / hide. But! The content underneath is overlapped. It's a longer vertical page, I am trying to add a condition to push the element that get's overlapped, underneath the overlay so down (`margin-top: 300px;`)

But if

```
.sDetails2
```

is no longer display: block; remove the `margin-top: 300px;`

Element underneath:

```
.verticallparallaxwrapper section.content-guide { 
        margin-top: 300px; // add if .sDetails2 is display: block
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using jQuery's .slideToggle() or something similar rather than a plugin that seems to do the opposite of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, if I built the site originally!

Comment: If its an overlay, why would you let the user access the content underneath it?

Comment: Then... get rid of it and use the three lines of jQuery I've proposed in my answer? :)

Comment: why not use position relative, so when the popup is displayed it pushes next elements further down the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use jQuery's .slideToggle() to achieve this. Something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2ds4pjr/), perhaps?

JS

```
$('#whatevertriggerspopup').on('click', function() {
    $('#thepopup').slideToggle();
});
```

**EDIT**

for the margin fix:

CSS

```
.toggle-margin {
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#whatevertriggerspopup').on('click', function() {
    $('#thepopup').slideToggle();
    $('#thethingbelowthepopup').toggleClass('.toggle-margin');
});
```

Comment: So, I changed to .slideToggle and the problem still persists (but now it's slides in!)

Comment: @Nooneknows which part of the problem still persists? The lower section doesn't move?

Comment: Yup. It's a pretty expansive site... I'm trying to just write function now an a if condition to margin-top

Comment: @Nooneknows ok, sounds like something else is at play that I cannot see. But I've updated my answer with something that should work for you. It toggles a class on the second element that adds/removes `margin-top:300px` whenever the popup is shown/hidden.

Comment: @Nooneknows aaand I'm guessing that the other element isn't moving because its position is something other than `position:relative`. Otherwise you could just drop the margin part completely and it would move **relative**  to the element above it when it slides out.

Comment: Toggling the toggle-margin worked, but I agree, very strange. (everything is set to relative!) Oh well. One up for ya and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, unfortunately this simple solution only works if the actual inline style attribute is the one being set:

```
style="display:block;"
```

It won't work if the display is being set via a classname and relevant CSS rule.

```
var myOverlay = document.getElementsByClassName('sDetals2')[0];
var movingElement = document.getElementsByClassName('content-guide')[0];
var displayCheck = myOverlay.style.display;

if(displayCheck == 'block'){
   movingElement.style.margin = '300px 0 0 0';
}
else{
   movingElement.style.margin = '0';
}
```